# SharePoint Web Error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'ClockControlWebPart' does not have a strong name

I can't understand this error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most lilkey assembly you are building is strongly named and as result it can't reference assemblies that are not strongly named.

Note that each error C# compiler produces have code in the beginning (like CS1234). Searching on for this code will likely give you article on MSDN with explanation of the error and most common cases when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

make it strong named , using sn.exe and add it to safer controls in your web.config, hope this shall remove the error.